# Convert list of strings into JSON with Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have a list of Strings like so:

```
List<String> errors = []
errors << 'Your password was bad.'
errors << 'Your feet smell.'
errors << 'I am having a bad day.'
```

That I would like converted (via Groovy/3rd party libs) into JSON:

```
{
    [
        "Your password was bad.",
        "Your feet smell.",
        "I am having a bad day."
    ]
}
```

My best attempt thus far is **nasty** and I expect there is a much quicker/leaner/more efficient way of doing this:

```
static String errorsToJSON(List<String> errors) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
    sb.append('{ ')
    List<String> errorJsons = []
    errors.each {
        errorJsons << '\"${it}\"'
    }

    // https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html
    List<String> list = Joiner.on(',').join(errorJsons)
    list.each {
        sb.append(it)
    }
    sb.append(' }')

    sb.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need for a third-party library, [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/json.html) can do this all for you.

```
def json = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(errors)
assert json == '["Your password was bad.","Your feet smell.","I am having a bad day."]'
```

Comment: Another way it is to `import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson` and use: `toJson(errors)` (it seems cleaner to me).